# What do you call someone who doesn't observe details?

Tags: single-word-requests, names

My mom is so ... that I had to explain that I was being sarcastic.

Comment: Inattentive? Or synonyms of inattentive https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/inattentive

Comment: I think @StuartF's ***inattentive*** is probably more common for the cited context that all the next three alternatives put together. Assuming we're not veering off into "less accurate" terms such as ***stupid, preoccupied, indifferent,...***

Answer (score 1):

*Obtuse* or *Thick* apply in such contexts.

**Caveat**: Using these words for one's mom would be considered downright rude.

*Obtuse*

> lacking sharpness or quickness of sensibility or intellect :
> INSENSITIVE, STUPID

*He is too obtuse to take a hint*.

*Thick*

> obtuse, stupid

[Merriam-Webster]

*Perhaps, you should go with *imperceptive**.

Comment: I always thought "unperceptive" was the usual negative, but it seems both "unperceptive" and "imperceptive" are in dictionaries. How ironic.

Comment: Funny that I thought "imperceptive" was the usual negative. BTW, how does this constitute an irony? :)

Answer (score 0):

maybe *guileless* - considering the sentence.

guileless: devoid of guile; innocent and without deception.

Answer (score 0):

My mother is this way.  I say that she is just so "literal".  She takes everything that you say as face value and doesn't seem to understand sarcasm.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I doubt anyone will say it but it is perfect

SLAPDASH
done too hurriedly and carelessly.

Comment: This would be improved with a dictionary definition

Comment: It doesn't fit with 'My mom is so ... that I had to explain that I was being sarcastic.'